# React, Standard & ESLint - 'propTypes' is not defined. (no-undef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint, standardjs

I'm using:

- [React 16.2.0](https://reactjs.org/)
- [Standard 10.0.3](https://standardjs.com/)
- [Babel ES Lint 8.2.3](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint)
- [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties 7.0.0-beta.40](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)
- [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

I have this in my `package.json`:

```
"standard": {
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

I'm writing my React components like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}
  static defaultProps = {}
  myMethod = () => {}
  render () {}
}
```

I'm seeing these errors:

> 'propTypes' is not defined. (no-undef)
>
> 'defaultProps' is not defined. (no-undef)
>
> 'myMethod' is not defined. (no-undef)

These errors are winding me up every time I open a component file!

How do I either make ES Lint recognise these class properties as valid, or tell ES Lint to ignore them..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [Standard](https://standardjs.com/) to 11.0.1 and the errors are gone.

Thank goodness for that!